# Is mudgal puran with english translation available?

Tags: ganesha

Mudgal puran is often quoted for iconic representations of lord Ganesha. Somewhere i rememeber reading that Ganesha puran and Mudgal puran are 2 important sacred texts for Ganapatyas.  Ganesha puran has been translated in to english by many. However search regarding  mudgal puran translation did not yield result. Is there a english translation of mudgal puran.